# Can I combine an SKAction runBlock with the SKNode - runAction:completion:? function?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

when I call the runAction:completion:? function of a SKSpriteNode, and pass in a SKAction runBlock action the call back routine never gets called.

Comment: Post the code so we can have a better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is possibly because SpriteKit has no way of knowing when your block actually stopped affecting the node in question. If the API was better designed maybe it'd give you a way of calling the completion from your block, but it doesn't. However, you can call whatever you'd call in the completion block yourself within your block.

Edit: Yes, the called (in this case SpriteKit) does know when your block ends executing, but your block may perform deferred calls that will further affect the node in question, so it can't be certain the action really ended. For example, think of a block that triggers a timer that varies a certain property over time.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you assuming this is the way it works, or do you know this is the way  it works, and if so do you have a source that states this?  I could think of many ways spriteKit could know when my block is done, specifically since it is the entity that calls it.  I'll be happy to mark this the answer, I just want to be sure.

Comment: very unsatisfying, but I guess I'll just have to accept the fact that this is just the way it is, and it is not documented by Apple. Thanks for you help

Comment: @FierceMonkey agreed, SK's documentation is far from being awesome. I'm doing my first and last game with it ATM.